# Pie of pie charts in Highcharts Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I'm trying to create a pie of pie charts like they show in excel. I could not find a pie of pie support in highcharts for reactjs. I can create two pie charts but I can't seem to connect them with lines as shown in the image below. Is there a workaround for this?
click on one  slice of pie chart and its  move to  its more detail  like in i share links below

[Pie of pie Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AtJ3.png)

[click this for  more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301983/pie-of-pie-charts-in-highcharts)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Isn't this a 1:1 copy of the already existing [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42301983/8106583) you linked? How is your question different from that one? Doesn't the answer there work for you?

Comment: Hi @Muhammad_Rehan, There is no such chart type by default in Highcharts, but you can create it with some customization. You can use two pie series with different position, connect them in `click` event: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.point.events.click and add the lines by using `SVGRenderer` class: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path